# Telerik UI Grid: Bind to collection member of model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a model with the following member:

```
 public class Foo
 {
    public List< Tuple<String, String> > bar { get; set; }
    //more fields that do not matter in this case
 }
```

I have a form in my view (strongly typed to `Foo`) to fill my different members, but now I want to use the Telerik UI Grid to have my users fill in their `bar`.

It is clear that

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Foo>()
           .Name("Grid")
             .Columns(columns =>
             {
                 columns.Bound(e => e.bar);
                 columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy();      }).Width("30%");
             })
```

does not work.

I also tried replacing `List<Tuple<String, String>>` with `List<Bar>` and create an extra model called `Bar`. I can then bind my grid to this model, but I have no idea how I can add it to the list in `Foo`, so that I have the data entered when submitting the form.

Any idea if this is possible and if yes, how to do this? Can't seem to find an example that does this.

Comment: For showing the collection you could use a `ForeignKey` column of the [grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn). But for the inserting data into the collection you have to think of adding separate logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your grid needs to "work" with a list, not a model containing a list.

So I would rather go for something like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.bar)//the grid is now working with the list
              .Name("Grid")
              .Columns(columns => {
                  columns.Bound(e => e.Item1);//first item in tuple
                  columns.Bound(e => e.Item2);//second item in tuple
                  columns.Command(command => {
                    command.Edit();
                    command.Destroy();
                  }).Width("30%");
              })
```

That said, I'm not sure that the grid will work with a `Tuple<string, string>`... but that's worth a try ;)

Comment: It won't work with a Tuple<String, String> due to lack of constructor without parameters. That being said, I could do it with Model.Bar. (Just exchange the tuple for an object representing my data)

Comment: @KWyckmans Right, I thought that there was something like that, but didn't remember ;)